# PhoneGap: Device Plugin Not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, npm

I can't seem to get the device plugin working with my Cordova/PhoneGap project.

I'm using Cordova `3.3.1-0.1.2`.

I made sure to follow the docs and installed the plugin like so:

```
C:\ProjectFolder>plugman --platform android --project platforms/android --plugin org.apache.cordova.device
```

It installed fine then I went on to include the `<feature>` tag in my `config.xml`

```
 <widget  ...
 <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
 <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
 <feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
 </feature>
 </widget>
```

However still nothing it appears when I attempt to print `device.platform` or any other property. I get the deviceready event but the device object is undefined.

As `typeof device` prints `undefined`.

I've also notice that my `<preference>` tags seem to be ignored as well as I seem to be able to rotate my app even when it's supposed to be fixed in `portrait`.

Can anyone help me? :(

Comment: It does look like the plugin wasn't correctly installed since Cordova is supposed to update `config.xml` automatically on its own. Make sure your `config.xml` is located OUTSIDE the `www` folder. Starting from 3.3.0, the config file has been moved.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git` and import `cordova.js` correctly into your html file it should work just fine.